# resolution of graphics to print

Tags: resolution

I design graphics and I have so many they clog my computer, and many too large for downloads in my shop when I use 300 resolution on photo shop.  I design my graphics at 300 resolution.  They are large and easy to work with. I resize my 300 resolution to 100 resolution and have never found any difference in printing, size, or quality.  It saves space and allows me to have them available as downloads. Am I missing something?

Comment: Why the same question twice? http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/64939/changing-resolution-from-300-to-100-dpi

Comment: Sorry, my first time on here.  Just getting started and trying to figure it all out.   Wasn't sure it went on right.

Comment: There is a edit text below, you can edit anytime your question to clarify it, as long as you do not change it completly and disarticulate it from answers ;o) (Not this one, lets close it)

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/13780/55950) old question about this. Should help you out and explain things.