# Why do images show as 96 DPI in properties but 72 PPI in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, print-design, resolution

I have an image that if I right click on and go to properties>details it tells me the resolution is 96 DPI. If I open the image in Photoshop, it gives me a PPI of 72. I'm wondering why they are different and why does it give me DPI instead of PPI when I right click on the photo? Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does Photoshop call ppi "resolution"?](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/54995/why-does-photoshop-call-ppi-resolution)

Comment: The accepted answer there should explain well enough the answer to your question

Comment: What I don't understand is that every other photo I checked, the DPI and the PPI are the same. It seems when I get an image that is 96 DPI under properties>details then most of the time it shows a PPI of 72 in Photoshop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have an image that if I right click on

On windows? On the file manager?

96 ppi is a default resolution asigned to untaged images on windows. 72 ppi is one standarized for some other aplications.

I do not know why they are diferent in your document. There is a chance your image simply has not that value asigned and the two aplications are just asigning the default one. No big deal.

DPI is an incorrect terem. A DPI is a value for prints, not for electronic images. Some aplications simply has that term wrong.

Comment: The why is because 72ppi was Apples actual monitor resolution way back when (specifically so it would work nicely with the 144dpi printer). Windows decided to create a default roughly 1/3 larger than that to get around some idea about monitor vs paper viewing distance... or something like that. But it's basically all irrelevant now anyway :)

Comment: I meant I do not know why the user's document is diferent. I do know the historical reasons ;o) but thanks.

Comment: Oh, right. Then yeh it would be because the image has no ppi set and is taking the different defaults.. As you said :)